# Using jQuery, how do I change the elements html value? (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a ajax request I want to change content of my div.

```
<div id="d1">202</div>
```

So I want to change the content to a different number.

```
$('d1').InnerText???
```

Also, say I wanted to increment the number, how could I do that? Do I have to convert to int?

Answer (score 37):

```
$("#di").html('My New Text');
```

Check out the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val).

If you wanted to increment the number, you would do

```
var theint = parseInt($("#di").html(),10)
theint++;
$("#di").html(theint);
```

P.S. Not sure if it was a typo or not, but you need to include the `#` in your selector to let jQuery know you are looking for an element with an ID of `di`. Maybe if you come from prototype you do not expect this, just letting you know.

Comment: needed to do the same thing. google, first result stack, first answer works a treat. this is why i love stack! +1

Answer (score 5):

This would changed the inner text of your HTML element.

```
$('#d1').text(parseInt(requestResponse)++);
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're embedding html like `<b>blah</b>` I'd suggest using `$("#di").text()` as it'll automatically escape things like <, > and &, whereas `.html()` will not.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) function:

```
$("#d1").text($("#d1").text() + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#d1').html("Html here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#d1').html("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

if your value is a pure text (like 'test') you could use the text() method as well. like this:

```
$('#d1').text('test'); Or $('#d1').html('test');
```

anyway, about the problem you are sharing, I think you might be calling the JavaScript code before the HTML code for the DIV is being sent to the browser. make sure you are calling the jQuery line in a <script> tag after the <div>, or in a statement like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#d1').text('test');
    }
);
```

this way the script executes after the HTML of the div is parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").innerHTML="your text goes here..";
```