# Change parameter based on select value

Tags: jquery

I am using this neat script to develop a select menu.

http://exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html#plugin_options

I am using the follow example from the site:

```
$('#list4').jqDropDown({
   optionChanged: function(){alert('option changed...');},
   defaultStyle: false
   containerName: 'theContainer'
   toggleBtnName: 'awesomeToggleClass'
   optionListName: 'thisListIsRocking'
});
```

I am looking for a function on the `optionChanged` which will allow me to change a php variable based on the value that has been selected.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where you said "allow me to change a php variable based on the value that has been selected"?

Comment: Basically the selector lets the user choose Countries. I would like when for example i select france - the email address next to my selector to change to france@domain.com

Comment: Throw an AJAX request into that function, should take care of it.

Comment: To do this - somehow i need to define a PHP variable i believe..

Comment: AJAX request sounds good, i think it's what i need so that page doesn't refresh.. - not sure how to do this..

Comment: Ahh, that's a separate tutorial in itself, one which has been covered many times before. Try searching on "jQuery AJAX PHP tutorial", it'll get you started in the right direction :)

Comment: i am using Wordpress - could it be a simple solution ?

Comment: After doing some research - i dont think i would require AJAX request - i could change the text of a div just by using JQuery ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537554/using-jquery-how-do-i-change-the-elements-html-value-div