# How to change the value of a div dynamically on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to create a game. For that I need some help...
How can I change the value of a div by clicking on it?

```
<div class="block1">    
         <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

js code :

```
 $( ".block1" ).click(function() {
          $( "#one" ).css('display','block');
          $( "#two" ).css('display','none');
          $( "#three" ).css('display','none');
          $( "#four" ).css('display','none');   
           });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HZjdP/1/)

Comment: The code here doesn't match the code in your fiddle. What exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery, how do I change the elements html value? (div)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537554/using-jquery-how-do-i-change-the-elements-html-value-div) or rather [jquery set value of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570905/jquery-set-value-of-div)

Comment: Change the 'value' *how*?

Comment: Your fiddle has duplicate id's for elements and is thus invalid HTML and none of the answers accessing an element by id will work properly.

Comment: Hasn't this been already answered thousand times?...

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text` to change the text

```
$('#one').text('New value')
```

You can use the this context inside the click event to change the text of currently clicked div.

```
 $(".block1").click(function () {
      $(this).text("New value")
  });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZjdP/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$( ".block1" ).click(function() {
$(this).html("Div Content")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach - 1**

```
$("#one")[0].textContent = "test";
```

**Approach - 2**

```
$("#one").prop('textContent', "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery

You can use .text() to change or get the text inside the div

```
$("#one").text('Some new text');
```

You can use .html() to change or get the html inside the div

```
$("#one").html('<p>Some new html</p>');
```

For form elements such as  you can use .val()

```
$("#one").val('1');
```

Comment: But how to generate it dynamically?

Comment: I've given you the tools, now you can solve that